# How can I find the value of this [pathological] function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fractals, continuity

A few months ago, while attempting to create a parameterization of the Hilbert curve, I discovered an interesting function, given by the summation...

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text{sgn}\left(\cos(nx)\right)}{n}$$

...where $\text{sgn}$ is the signum function...

$$\text{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1&x>0\\0&x=0\\-1&x<0\end{cases}$$

The function is noteworthy for being nowhere differentiable and nowhere continuous. I have found it nigh impossible to evaluate the function for any $x$ save integer multiples of $2\pi$ (where the sum diverges).

The graph of the function (shown below) seems to be a self-similar fractal, but I don't know enough about fractals to verify this. Even if I did, I'm not sure what I would do with this information.

[image]

Anyway, how can I find the value of $f(x)$ for arbitrary $x$?

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question, but I must say this plot looks amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For rational multiples of $\pi$, $\text{sgn}(\cos(nx))$ is periodic and the sum can be done in "closed form" in terms of the Digamma function.  Thus for $x = 3\pi/4$, Maple tells me:

```
sum(sum(signum(cos(k*3*Pi/4))/(k+8*m),k=1..8),m=0..infinity);
```

$$ \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\ln(2)}{4} + \frac{\Psi(1/8) - \Psi(3/8)}{4} $$

Comment: This is precisely what I thought when I read the post. The problem seemed very straightforward for rational multiples of $\pi$. It seems like other forms of $x$ would be much harder, if not completely intractable. $+1$

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I should I try approximating $f(x)$ for other $x$ by taking the limit of a sequence of rational multiples of $\pi$ which converges to $x$?

Comment: In principle yes, but the discontinuities may make it hard to control the approximations.

Answer (score 3):

This is more like an extended comment. From the Fourier series

$$ \operatorname{sign}(\cos(x)) = \frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} \cos((2k+1)x), $$

we heuristically compute that

\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{n(2k+1)}\cos(n(2k+1)x) \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \frac{r_2(l)}{l} \cos(lx) \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{\mathrm{k} \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus\{0\}} \frac{\cos(|\mathrm{k}|x)}{|\mathrm{k}|},
\end{align*}

where $r_2(\cdot)$ is the [sum of squares functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function) and the second step follows by rearranging the sum according to the value of $l = n(2k+1)$, although establishing the validity of such manipulation would be a non-trivial task.

The following is the plot of of the partial sum $\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{l=1}^{1000} \frac{r_2(l)}{l} \cos(lx)$ evaluated at points of the form $x = \frac{k \pi}{1025}$ for $|k| \leq 1025$, replicating OP's figure.

[image]